# Glyph icon vertically down next to image

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place `glyphicon` next to image close to bottom, however it comes to the mid of the image.

```
 <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img src="@Url.Content(Model.DefaultImagePath)" alt="Image" height="150" width="150"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="color: #292929; background-color: #E3DAC9;"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: #292929;background-color: #E3DAC9"></span>
         </div>
```

How it is rendered:

[image]

This is how I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:bottom`

```css
span {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/150/150" alt="Image" height="150" width="150" />
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="color: #292929; background-color: #E3DAC9;"></span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: #292929;background-color: #E3DAC9"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `vertical-align: baseline;` style declaration as follows:

```
<div>
    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.DefaultImagePath)" alt="Image" height="150" width="150"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="color: #292929; background-color: #E3DAC9;vertical-align: baseline;"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: #292929;background-color: #E3DAC9;vertical-align: baseline;"></span>
</div>
```

Then both the icons will align to the bottom of their parent div.

Note that putting that many style declarations in inline is not a good idea. They could be extracted as a css class.